# Python: Using readine() in "for line in file:" Loop

Tags: python

Lets say I have a text file that looks like:

```
a
b
start_flag
c
d
e
end_flag
f
g
```

I wish to iterate over this data line by line, but when I encounter a 'start_flag', I want to iterate until I reach an 'end_flag' and count the number of lines in between:

```
newline = ''
for line in f:
    count = 0
    if 'start_flag' in line:
        while 'end_flag' not in newline:
            count += 1
            newline = f.readline()
        print(str(count))
```

What is the expected behavior of this code? Will it iterate like:

```
a
b
start_flag
    c
    d
    e
    end_flag
f
g
```

Or:

```
a
b
start_flag
    c
    d
    e
    end_flag
c
d
e
end_flag
f
g
```

Comment: Why ask us how it will work, rather than just trying it and finding out for yourself? As far as I recall, mixing `readline` with iteration on a file is not well supported, but using `next(f)` (or another `for` loop) would probably  work like your first example since files are their own iterators.

Comment: I will test it out and post an answer if no one else wants to. Thanks for the suggestion too.

Comment: my result showed it being: a,b,flag,fag,c,d,e,f,g....so i got none of your alternatives....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any need to use `readline()`.  Try it like this:

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    count = 0
    counting = False
    for line in f:
        if 'start_flag' in line:
            counting = True
        elif 'end_flag' in line:
            counting = False
            #do something with your count result
            count = 0 #reset it for the next start_flag
        if counting is True:
            count += 1
```

This handles it all with the `if` statements in the correct order, allowing you to just run sequentially through the file in one go.  You could obviously add more operations into this, and do things with the results, for example appending them to a list if you expect to run into multiple start and end flags.

Comment: The general consensus seems to be don't mix the for loop iterator and the readline function as Blcknght said. Thanks for the input from everyone.

Comment: In general it's very difficult to mess with the order of reading through a file.  If you can make it work easily in a simple, sequential fashion, you're probably doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
enter = False
count = 0
for line in f:
  if 'start_flag' in line:
    enter = True
  if 'end_flag' in line:
    print count
    count = 0
    enter = False
  if enter is True:
    count+=1
```